# Numerical solutions for $y'' = \sin(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose $f$ is continuous on an interval $\vert y - y_0 \vert \leq b$, where $y_0$ is a fixed point. It can be shown, that this equation can be written as $$y'\frac{dy'}{dy} = \sin(y)$$

now multiplying by $dy$ and integrating both sides over the above interval, I have $$(y')^2(y) -(y')^2(y_0)=2\int_{y_0}^{y}\sin(t)dt$$

and the second order equation reduces to the first order equation

$$(y')^2 = (y')^2(y_0)+2(\cos(y)-\cos(y_0))$$

and with initial conditions $y'(0) = \beta>0$, $y(0)=0$ I get that $$(y')^2 = \beta^2+2\cos(y)-2$$

$$y' = \sqrt{\beta^2+2\cos(y)-2}$$

which is an equation that could be approximated with Euler's method. The problem is that the expression lies in a square root, so the approximations become undefined very quickly. Currently I'm looking at the midpoint method and maybe rewriting this as a Taylor series, but I wanted to run this with more experienced folk.

Does it make sense to approach this equation with Euler, or is this ( and equations of this type ) not well suited for the method?

Comment: Do you mean explicit euler or implicit. Also, to prevent it from being undefined, i think the condition ought to be that $\beta > 2$

Comment: I'm using explicit Euler

Comment: My advice: never use explicit euler if you can help it. If you want an explicit method, there are other better ones out there

Comment: I just realized I didn't give you an example. Explicit Runge Kutta is a good alternative to Explicit euler. It's a family of integrators

Comment: Since elliptic functions are involved you can probably use Jacobi functions and especially amplitude to solve it https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html, i.e turn $2\cos(y)-2$ into $-4\sin(y/2)^2$.

Comment: In general this order reduction is not very helpful for a numerical integration. Use the two-dimensional first order system $y'=z$, $z'=\sin(y)$ and apply the chosen numerical method. Or use Stormer-Verlet, Numerov etc. that are methods directly for second order equations.

Comment: Agree with Lutz^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, a better approach is to let $y = x_1$, so

$$\begin{align} y' &= x_1' = x_2 \\ y'' &= x_2' = \sin x_1 \end{align}$$

We can write this as the system

$$\begin{align} x_1' &= x_2 \\ x_2' &= \sin x_1 \end{align}$$

You can now use Euler, Runge-Kutta...

We can also draw a phase portrait and see solution behaviors as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-\sin y \implies 2y' y''=2y' \sin y\implies \frac{dy'^2}{dx}=2 \frac{dy}{dx} \sin y.$$
D.w.r.t. x, we get
$$y'^2=2 \int \sin y dy +A \implies y'^2=A-2\cos y$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\pm  \sqrt{A-2\cos y} \implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{A-2\cos y}}=\pm x+B.$$